# Chat panel UI for wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using rich text box to show users messages. What I want to do is that I want to show sender messages on right and receiver messages on left of screen. I have tried various techniques like changing flow direction but failed in doing so.Any help will be appreciated

Here is my xaml:

```
<wpfTool:RichTextBox>                            
    <FlowDocument>
         <BlockUIContainer></BlockUIContainer>
         <Paragraph>
             <InlineUIContainer></InlineUIContainer>
             <Run Text="{Binding ChatBlock}"  />
             <LineBreak/>
         </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
 </wpfTool:RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Why don't you use 2 different RichTextBox

Comment: @eranotzap If I user to rich textbox all sender messages will be show at tp and all receiver messages will be shown at bottom, right?

Comment: unless you place them aside each other..

Comment: Could you show us what you tried already ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do some templating like this

```
    <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  BorderThickness="2"
                  BorderBrush="Red"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Name="ItemsControl1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph Name="Para">
                            <Run Text="{Binding Text}" />
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Sender">
                        <Setter TargetName="Para"
                                Property="TextAlignment"
                                Value="Right" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}"
                                 Value="Receiver">
                        <Setter TargetName="Para"
                                Property="TextAlignment"
                                Value="Left" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I have created a sample project [here](http://www.freeuploadsite.com/do.php?id=65533)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740674/how-do-i-set-formatted-text-in-silverlight-richtextbox) post; something like the below should help

```
    public static void setRtf(ref RichTextBox rtfBox, string text, bool fromMe = false)
    {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.FontFamily = rtfBox.FontFamily;
        p.TextAlignment = fromMe ? TextAlignment.Left : TextAlignment.Right;
        Run pTxt = new Run();
        pTxt.Text = text;
        p.Inlines.Add(pTxt);
        rtfBox.Blocks.Add(p);
    }
```